# Method in Java that takes any type as a parametr

Tags: java, generics, abstract-data-type

For example I want to write my own print array method:

```
public void printArray(T[] array) {
        System.out.print("[");
        for (T element : array) {
            System.out.print(element + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("]");
    }
```

but if I try to use this method on primitive types, I get an error : converting boolean to Object is not possible. Is there any way to work with primitive type in Java more abstract?

Answer (score 4):

Generics simply don't work with primitive types. Overload your method for the various primitive types like [`Arrays.toString(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28boolean%5B%5D%29) does.

Comment: So no generic for primitive types. Thank you!